# Playing a mp4 video using Iframe disable autoplay on google chrome

Tags: html, iframe, autoplay

I'm having an issue with `Iframe autoplay="0"` on Google Chrome.
I have tried every thread and and forum and nothing has worked.

I need the video to pause as soon as the page loads. I cannot use the `<video> </video>` tag because I need information to pull from a separate library into a main video div.

I haven't found any JavaScript that works and autostart="0" , autostart="false" autoplay="0" , autoplay="false" doesnt work either.

Link : [Aza TV](http://rcmtest.co.za/azatv/)

```js
<script>
$(".video-1, .video-2, .video-3").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".video_case iframe").prop("src", $(event.currentTarget).attr("href"));
});
</script>
```

```css
.video_wrapper { width:67%; padding:10px; box-sizing:border-box; float:left; min-height:50px;border: thin solid #F60; border-radius:5px 5px;}



.nextvideo_wrapper { width:31%; padding:8px; box-sizing:border-box; float:left; min-height:400px;border: thin solid #F60; border-radius:5px 5px;margin-left:10px; background:#333;}
```

```html
<div class="video_wrapper">
    <iframe  name="someFrame" id="someFrame" width="100%" height="420" src="http://41.76.210.2/vod/azamusica_VictoriaKimani_webisode22_20151022_HDO.mp4?autoplay=0"  controls ></iframe>
</div>

<div class="nextvideo_wrapper">
<iframe  src="libraries/azamuzika.php" width="100%" height="400px" bg=ffffff&text=000000" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: The "I cannot use a tag" does not compute. Show the actual data you have and let us see if you can use a tag anyway. For example by document.writing it into the iframe or by using document.createElement. Also is the link to AZA your page or an example of some page that does what you need?

Comment: Hi Thanks for getting back to me. I do realize that I can use the tag but I was trying to keep it as simple as possible. I used the video tag and the video autopaused which is great but then the videos in my library opened in another tab instead of the frame. I am also pretty begginner when it comes to this kind of stuff. The link to the website is supplied above but here it is again , so you can get an idea of what im trying to achieve.  http://rcmtest.co.za/azatv/entertainment/

Comment: @mplungjan The "I cannot use the tag" by the OP was caused by the use of unescaped HMTL in the post. I have edited and added backticks to make things clearer.

Comment: @MrLister ah- I did not suspect that since there was a lot of other tags posted ok. Anyway my comment still stands. He could still use video tag

Answer (score 0):

Please note your selector does not actually match the html you posted.

To keep it simple try to add `&autoplay=0` to your urls - if that does not work, try this - I gave the actual iframe an ID of iFrame1 and write the video tag into it

```
var vid = '<video controls="controls"><source src="__VIDEO__" type="video/mp4" /><!--[if gt IE 6]><object width="640" height="375" classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"><! [endif]--><!--[if !IE]><!--><object width="640" height="375" type="video/quicktime" data="__VIDEO__.mp4"><!--<![endif]--><param name="src" value="__VIDEO__" /><param name="autoplay" value="false" /></object></video>';
$(".video-1, .video-2, .video-3").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var ifrm = $('#iFrame1').get(0); // get the DOM object
  ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
  ifrm.document.write(vid.replace(/__VIDEO__/g,$(event.currentTarget).attr("href"));
  ifrm.document.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all the possible solutions but nothing worked for local video bindings. I believe best solution would be to fix using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ownVideos = $("iframe");
    $.each(ownVideos, function (i, video) {                
        var frameContent = $(video).contents().find('body').html();
        if (frameContent) {
            $(video).contents().find('body').html(frameContent.replace("autoplay", ""));
        }
    });
});
```

**Note:** It'll find all the iframes on document ready and loop through each iframe contents and replace/remove `autoplay` attribute. This solution can be use anywhere in your project. If you would like to do for specific element then use the code under `$.each` function and replace `$(video)` with your iframe element id like `$("#myIFrameId")`.